# How to make SORTKEY for irregular observations

Tags: sorting, sas, dataset

I'd like to make "SORTKEY" like the below. It's not the same observations for each one.
Basically, each one is 3 obs but if flg=1 then "SORTKEY" includes that observation.
In this example, it means SORTKEY = 2 is 4 obs, SORTKEY ^=2 is 3 obs.
Is there the way to make the SORTKEY manually?. If you have a good idea, please give me some advice.

I want the following dataset, using the "test" dataset.

```
/*
SORTKEY NO FLG
 1 　　　1 　0
 1 　　　2 　0
 1 　　　3 　0
 2 　　　4 　0
 2 　　　5 　0
 2 　　　6 　0
 2 　　　7 　1
 3 　　　8 　0
 3 　　　9 　0
 3 　　　10  0
*/

data test;
 input no flg;
 cards;
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 1
8 0
9 0
10 0
;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sequence counter to track the 3-rows-per-sortkey requirement.

Example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  retain sortkey 1;
  seq+1;
  if seq > 3 and flag ne 1 then do;
    seq = 1;
    sortkey+1;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a very smart program. Nice!